# VueJs Checkbox issues

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, vuejs3

I created a user page with checkboxes but I am having some issues:

1. Unable to see the checked boxes on the pages after reload,
2. I can not uncheck the values in the EditForm, if i try to click on checkbox the value is pushing to the array even it is already exist in the array

script:

```js
isChecked(teamPermission) {
    let checkStatus = this.currentTeam.permissions.some((permission) => {
        return teamPermission.id === permission.permissionType;
    });

    return checkStatus;
},

newPermission(permission) {
    // console.log("NewPermission", permission);
 
    this.currentTeam.permissions.push({
        permissionType:permission.id,
        teamId:this.currentTeam.id
    })

    this.newAssignedPermissions = this.currentTeam.permissions;
    // console.log('ASSIGNED PERMISSIONS', assignedPermissions)
    // console.log('NEW ASSIGNED PERMISSIONS', this.newAssignedPermissions);

    return this.newAssignedPermissions;
},
```

template:

```html
<ul
  v-for="permission in permissions"
  :key="permission.id"
>
  <input
    class="form-check-input mt-0"
    type="checkbox"
    :id="permission.id"
    :value="{ permissionType: permission.id }"
    :checked="isChecked(permission)"
    @input="newPermission(permission)"
    aria-label="Checkbox for following text input"
  />

  <label
    :for="permission.id"
    class="ms-2"
  >
    {{ permission.name.toLowerCase() }}
  </label>
</ul>
```

UI is not showing the the existing permissions but when I click edit and select a new checkbox UI is showing the selected checkboxes and also when I unselect the checkbox, it still pushing the values making the duplicate checked values:

```html
<li
  v-for="givenPermissions in newAssignedPermissions"
  :key="givenPermissions.id"
>
  {{ permissions[givenPermissions.permissionType - 1].name.toLowerCase() }}
</li>
```

Comment: i recommend u to set up a playground - https://sfc.vuejs.org/, so we can understand better ur issue and help u

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, this is probably related to you using `@input` and `checked` properties, rather than using `v-model`. It's generally simpler to use `v-model` to control the value of form fields in Vue.

You can even use an object. Assuming you're using Vue 3, and permissions have IDs of `read` and `write`, you could have something like:

```js
// Populate with existing values
const permissions = ref({
    read: false,
    write: false,
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" v-model="permissions[permission.id]" />
```

That will both set the value of those inputs when `permissions` is updated, and in turn update the `permissions` object when the checkbox is checked or unchecked.

On load, you'd just need to initialise the `permissions` object, and on save, read its data.

**On a side note**, in your example you have the checkboxes as direct children of a `ul`, but if you use a `ul` for structure, each checkbox should be inside an `li`.

[For example, this is a simplified version of what I mean](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: I thank you for the response. Actually, I used v-model before using checked and @input, but  the already checked values are not showing as checked during the Editing.  for v-model I used set and get. but it did not work                                // assignedPermissions: {
    //   set(value) {
    //     this.currentTeam.permissions.push(value)
    //     console.log('VALUE',value);
    //   },
    //   get() {
    //     console.log('GETVALUE', Array.isArray(this.currentTeam.permissions),'Check');
    //     return this.currentTeam.permissions
    //   },
    // },

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing there but you don't need to use set and get, or push anything. If the `permissions` variable has a matching `id` that is true, the checkbox will be checked. If you base the object on the IDs of the permissions, their values are just booleans, whether or not the checkbox is checked. Worry about anything else - like `permissionType` - elsewhere.

Comment: I've added an example link to my answer, as the Vue playground seems to generate huge links for some reason.